# Issue calling different values from local storage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have 3 different values stored in local storage which are name, id and img I cannot seem to call the values individually.

```
      {Object.entries(localStorage).map(([key, value]) => {
        return <p>{value}</p>;
      })}
```

This will return all 3 values.

if I try something like

```
      {Object.entries(localStorage).map(([key, value]) => {
        return <p>{value.name}</p>;
      })}
```

then it returns nothing. same for .id or .img

the reason I'm not using something like let name = localStorage.getItem('name') is where the local storage is being set there is a counter that will add a 1 to each value ie name1, name2 and so on each time so that multiple values can be stored with a similar key, value structure so I can map through them all and then display them all.

any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can only store strings in local storage. So if you are storing a stringified json, you will need to parse it to be able to access its properties.

So try

```js
{
  Object.entries(localStorage).map(([key, value]) => {
    const parsedValue = JSON.parse(value);
    return <p>{ parsedValue.name }</p>;
  })
}
```

Comment: Even if I cut down the local storage to only name which is something simple like john i still can't just call it with something like value.name

Comment: @Brandon.b did you read the answer ? The object you save needs to be converted to a string before you store it to localstorage. So you need to parse it back to an object before you can use it as one. If you store it like `localStorage.setItem('name','John')` then the `value` is `john`. There will be no `.name` property.